# Timer not running inside the React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on the simple timer app in the React. Below is the code of what I have.

```
import React from "react"

const timer = (props) => {
 let time = 25;
 let processStatus = props.timerProcessStatus; // it comes as true
 if(processStatus === true) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(proccessStatus);
        countDown();
    }, 500)
 }

 function countDown(){
    time=time-1;
    console.log(time);
 }

 return (
    <div>
        <p id={props.statusId}>{props.timerStatus}</p>
        <p id={props.timerStatusId}>{time}:00</p>
    </div>
 )
}
export default timer;
```

And here is the snapshot of what I get in the browser
[image]

As it shows, the time variable changed to 24 (although I would expect it to decrease to 23 second time), it doesn't re-renders in the paragraph, where the content is {time}:00

Answer (score 3):

Incrementing a local variable won't cause a re-render of your component.

You need to put `time` in the state of your component. Updating the state will cause a re-render of the component which will then update the value of `time` in the `DOM`.

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

const timer = (props) => {
   const [time, setTime] = useState(25);  // local state 
 
   ...

   function countDown(){
      setTime(prevTime => prevTime + 1);  // update the state
   }

   ...
}
```

Every time `countDown` function will be called, it will update the state, causing a re-render of the component.

I suggest you to read [`React - State and Lifecycle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to understand why you need `time` as a state of the component.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code for the timer .

```
import React,{UseEffect,UseState} from 'react';

const timer=(props)=>{

const [time, setTime] = useState(25);

UseEffect(()=>{
let processStatus = props.timerProcessStatus;
 // it comes as true 
if(processStatus === true) { setTimeout(() => { console.log(proccessStatus); countDown(); }, 500) }
}, [])

function countDown(){ 
setTime(time--); 
}
// other code
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `setInterval` is the method to be used to run code/function in specific interval..
2. any async task should be run in `useEffect`

```js
function App(){
 const [time,setTime]=React.useState(25)
  let processStatus = true; // it comes as true

  function countDown() {
    // time = time - 1;
    setTime(prevTime=>prevTime-1)
    // console.log(time);
  }
  let timer;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (processStatus === true) {
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        countDown();
      }, 500);
    }
    return ()=>{
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox-{time}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it tries to create the time variable each time

so I would suggest to put the time variable in its parent component then just use

```
 function countDown(){
    let newTime = time;
    props.setTime(newTime - 1);
    console.log(newTime - 1);
 }
```